# No video signal at boot with custom built computer

Tags: display, hdmi, assembly

After booting my custom built computer, neither the VGA nor the HDMI methods from the video card seem to emit any signal to the display. I have tested both a regular VGA screen and a modern HDMI screen. Both did not receive signal. Below are the specifications from my computer build:

- Intel Core i5 3350P
- ASRock B75 Pro 3-M
- Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 ST1000 DM003 1000GB
- Corsair Vengeance LP CML 8GX 3M2 A1600 CGB Blue (2 cards)
- Cooler Master B Series B600
- Club 3D Radeon HD7870 XT Jokercard
- Samsung SH-224 BB Black
- Sharkoon T28 Case

The motherboard does not emit any beeps on startup. The CD tray opens properly and all fans spin. All cables are properly connected. All components are new and no damage was found on any of the components. The fans on the GPU spin aswell.

The VGA test we did was by using the onboard graphics from the Intel i5, but this gave no result. The HDMI test was from the GPU which did not emit any signal either. We have not been able to test out the DVI, could this be important to test, even though all the other methods did not work?

---

I was unable to comment on specific answers due to the migration and re-registration of an account here. To reply to everything that has been posted thus far:

- Both the power cords are connected. The 8-pin, and the 24-pin.
- The graphics card is connected properly, as it is generating heat and the fans spin.

I have no DVI-VGA adaptor, but if this could be the solution I'll be off to purchasing one.
The strange part is that everything works properly. Fans spinning, optical drive opening and trying to read a disk.

Comment: Try the DVI->VGA adapter on the 7870, see if that works.

Comment: hi man this is off topic so anyway this happend to me when I forgot to connect the extra 9v connector from PSU to mobo, but like @chopper3 said...

Comment: @PetterH There's no 9v power in a modern PC. Perhaps you mean the 12v EATX connector?

Comment: Why did you even hook up the CD and video card before testing the CPU and motherboard? You are making things much more complicated for yourself than they need to be.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm with you, most definitely... but it is common for people to assemble a system from the components they purchased, before they test them.  Not necessarily good, but common.

Comment: Please register your account on Server Fault and then log in here with the same credentials. You'll then be able to edit your question and add comments etc.

Answer (score 3):

First...

> All components are new

This does not exclude the possibility of a part arriving defective.  It happens all the time, and I'm pretty sure that almost everyone participating on a Stack Exchange site has either gotten a bad part purchased as new, or they know someone who has.  So, you cannot use this as a reason to assume that one or more of the parts used are not defective.

Second...

> no damage was found on any of the components

Not all defective parts will display physical manifestations to indicate they are defective.  In point of fact, most will not.

So, what you need to do is follow a number of standard diagnostics on your build.  You have been given good advice for things to look for already, but you need to step back to some basics.  I do not know to what extent you have already gone to as to your testing, but here is one of the first things you should try.

- Disconnect EVERYTHING, and I mean everything.  Mount your processor and the cooling fan.  Seat a single stick of Ram, and if possible, pull that stick of Ram from a working system... don't use one of the sticks you purchased.  Connect a working power supply to the motherboard.  If possible, again, use a power supply from a working machine instead of the one you purchased.  Connect a working monitor (either VGA, or DVI... doesn't matter since that board has both onboard).  Power the system.  You don't want a keyboard or mouse connected.  You don't want a hard drive or optical drive connected.  With this minimum configuration, you should be able to boot to the BIOS/UEFI System Browser... the BIOS/UEFI Splash Screen.

What will this prove?  Well, for one, if you use Ram and a power supply that you know is working (aka, from a working system), then you can safely assume the issue is either the processor or the motherboard.  If the system boots and you can enter the UEFI system browser, then you can power down, and swap out the Ram for one of the sticks you purchased.  Power up again.  If it works, you can swap out the power supply for the one you purchased.  Power up again.

You see where this is going?  You need to start from the bare minimum you can test, and slowly, piece by piece work your way up to the whole build if you want to find the component that is causing the issue.  Any number of bad components (including keyboards) can cause a system to not even get to the BIOS/UEFI.

And if you already did all this... you need to detail that fact in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your motherboard has all the power connectors; it has two:

- 24-pin ATX power connector on the right side
- 8-pin EATX power connector on the top side, by the processor

Check that you have **both** 6-pin power connectors on the graphics card hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

There are several fixes that I can think of:

- The Graphics Card is slightly detached from the motherboard. *Fix: open the computer case and push the card gently until you hear a 'click'.*
- Double check if you have plugged the cord to the right outpust port. Since your CPU has inner GPU, you might have mote then one of each ports. Connect the cord to one of the external (not onboard = inside the CPU, in this case.) GPU's ports and not the CPU's ports.
- Double check the setting of your screen, maybe it is tuned for another input (just look at the settings and see if something's wrong).